# DynamoDB Streams processing - multiple consumer receiving the same stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am working on a workflow app comprised mostly of microservices and batch jobs. The planned setup is this: We have a java based microservice consuming a particular DynamoDB stream via the Amazon Kinesis Client Library (KCL). Once a data stream is received, the service would do whatever processing it needs to do. The microservices run on EC2 machines and setup with a ALB and an Autoscaling Group.

Lets say during peak hours, the desired instances reach up to 4, which would mean having 4 instances of the running microservice. Here are my questions:

1. If all those instances are consuming the same stream and a record update is made that would trigger data n stream, would every instance receive that particular stream? Asking because I am concerned about duplicate processing. There have been no mentions in the documentation that would clarify this.
2. I did my due diligence and read some AWS documentation that would answer my question. All I found was you can only have a maximum of two consumers per DynamoDB shard. In this case, if I have multiple instances (4) of the same consumer, does that count as one consumer? or four consumers? and therefore I have to make two shards.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have every worker running its own instance of KCL then yes, each worker would see all events. More typical is you assign workers a lease to given shards, so that the work is not duplicated and thats what the [DynamoDB Kinesis Adapter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.KCLAdapter.html) does.
2. It depends on what you are doing with the workers, ideally they should only be doing the work assigned to them from the shard they have leased. But if you have each of your 4 workers polling the stream and duplicating work, then you will notice throttling, leading to higher stream latency.

Comment: if there are multiple shards, do data streams only come out of one shard? or all shards?

Comment: There is always 6 or more shards, you can call DescribeStream to understand how many shards there are. There is always 1 or more active shards which are currently accepting data.